# Amazon RDS: unable to grant permission to new role

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

I'm using AWS RDS (PostgreSQL) for our databases. I connected to the RDS instance with the master account. Created a new role for the databases.

- `CREATE USER myuser with password 'xxxx'`
- `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO myuser WITH GRANT OPTION`

However, it still shows that this new role do not have permissions on the tables under the public schema.

[image: screenshot of the missing privileges]

I also tried the "Grant All" bottom on the right hand side and save. It ran successfully but still show empty boxes.

Does anyone can tell me what's wrong on my settings?

Comment: refresh your IDE ?